# VB.Net Excel temporary file perf issue

Tags: excel, vb.net, temporary-files

I have a program that open some excel files to check values and then closed them.
Source files are on a network.
Everything is ok I can read values but in time I've got some perf issues it took some times more than 10 secondes to open them and read values.
I see that it created lot of temporary files with no data in it (0Ko). When I drop all temporary files the time back to less than a second.

Here is the source code :

```vb
Private Shared Sub Verification(listLots As List(Of String) )
Dim AppliExcel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()

    For Each numLot As String In listLots
        Dim nomFichier As String = GetCheminFichier(numLot)
        

        If System.IO.File.Exists(nomFichier) Then
            Dim Classeur As Workbook = Nothing
            Dim Feuille As Worksheet
            
            'free all existing workbook
            For Each wb As Workbook In AppliExcel.Workbooks
                wb.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
                ReleaseExcelObject(wb)
            Next

            'Open excel file
            Classeur = AppliExcel.Workbooks.Open(nomFichier,, True)

            ......  
            
            Classeur.Close(False)
            ReleaseExcelObject(Classeur)
            Classeur = Nothing
        end if

    Next

    AppliExcel.Quit()
    ReleaseExcelObject(AppliExcel)
End Sub
```

```vb
Private Shared Sub ReleaseExcelObject(obj As Object)
    Try
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
        obj = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        obj = Nothing
    Finally
        GC.Collect()
    End Try
End Sub
```

I wonder where is the problem and how to solve it.

Hope someone has an idea.
Kind regards
NC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug, not a feature, so there is no single correct solution.

Disable all Anti-virus. If that works, exclude the folder from AV, exclude the file type from AV.

if that doesn't work:

Change the location for excel temporary files.

Try using a different version of Windows for the Client, and for the Server.

Disable AutoSave and AutoRecover.

Disable Remote Differential Compression

There's a heap of other things that can cause problems like this - synchronization settings, privacy (reporting) settings, Windows Explorer update settings, thumbnail update settings ... start with the AV and see where you get.

Comment: Thank you for your reply david. Do you know if it's identified  by Microsoft ?

Comment: "It" can't be identified, because 'It' is always something different. Or, alternatively, it's been identified many different times -- at least once for each of the possibilities I mentioned. As you try each possibility, you can modify your question to exclude that, and to include information about your environment.